# node.js http: create persistent connection to host and sending request to several paths

Tags: node.js, http

I would like to create persistent http connection to host (api.development.push.apple.com) and send POST requests for many paths
(for example, '/3/device/1', '/3/device/2', etc.). Will code below create one connection with host or many connections for each http.request()?

```
var http = require('http');

http.request({
    host: 'api.development.push.apple.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/3/device/1',
    method: 'POST',
}).end();

http.request({
    host: 'api.development.push.apple.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/3/device/2',
    method: 'POST'
}).end();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is to use the same **Agent** for all of your requests.

If you don't specify an agent in the options object, the http module will use the **globalAgent**, which sets keepAlive to false by default.

So, create your agent, and use it for all requests:

```
var http = require('http');
var agent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }); // false by default

http.request({
    host: 'api.development.push.apple.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/3/device/1',
    method: 'POST',
    agent: agent, // use this agent for more requests as needed
}).end();
```

Comment: Are you aware of any changes needed to server code to make this work? I'd imaging calls to response.end() will be bad?

Comment: how do we know the connections are being re-used or re-created everytime?